# C# form doesn't size properly

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing a simple c# Windows Form project, and I found a problem in sizing my form.

If the form is smaller than size `(872,495)`, everything's ok, but when I try to increase it, (both axes) it keeps stuck at that size, cutting out the rest of it.

I think I already found the problem, but I'm not very sure about that: I got a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 laptop, which has a monitor of 14'', so I think the program make a sort of automatic useless "auto-resize".

In fact, the form is in the same position **with the same cuts** *(but fullscreen this time)* when I disable `AutoScaleMode` to `None`. Doing this doesn't solve the problem, because I don't want to have the form fullscreen, I don't want the user to scroll through the window, it's uncomfortable.

The only way I found, proving I'm quite right, is going into Display settings of my computer and change everything to 100%, but doing so the text is unreadable, and I have a headache after 5 minutes.
SO, is it a way to maintain the screen zoom to 150% and watch my form just with the original size of c# editor?

Comment: Perhaps you've already checked out these things, but here's what I am curious about: What are the values of: MaximumSize, AutoSize, and AutoSizeMode? A screenshot would help.

Comment: My goodness, you saved me. I put "autosize" on "true", and the control has forcefully resized, growing, because of that option... THANK YOU!! P.s. if you copy and paste that answer I'll give you the best answer.

Comment: Well yes, actually it's quite a forced idea because I can't have a good margin at the corner of the form so it's quite bad, but... it works! Actual situation: Maximum size:(2000,2000) in order not to have limits, Autosize: true, Autosize mode: GrowAndShrink

Comment: Thank you, and no problem. Also, if you would like the form size not to have any limits, I recommend that you set maximum size to (0,0). Although (2000, 2000) may be sufficient for your monitor, it may not be sufficient for other displays.

Comment: Perfect!!! ;) Probably, it's a bug/inappropriate "auto resize" function in the form, based on the size when it's fullscreen, **even if it's not!** But, by putting "Autosize" on "true" the problem is solved, because it makes the form forcefully grow. Thank you again!

Comment: Good evening Mr @MatthewKligerman , sorry to bother you, but may you take a look at my last question about PDFs in iTextSharp? Noone seems to have an answer, and I don't know what to do!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure it resizes correctly, make sure the following settings are as follows:

```
//Unless you want a maximum size, in which case, you can set the height and width. 
//When the maximum size is set to 0,0 the form has no limit in size besides the limits of the OS.
this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0); 

//Allows the form to resize itself.
this.AutoSize = true; 

//Allows the form to both grow and shrink
this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```